# InApp Billing Inactive credit card

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

i got an app to fix InApp Billing within it, the problem is
when you try to buy new item from the app, the market opens the item page, there is "Accept & Buy" button, and theres is a "Add Card" thats shows my credit cards i've already used before, but it shows none of my credit cards is active, just "Add Card" is active, so i need to add new credit card, but even when i add new one, it remains inactive, i've tried to buy games from market using same credit card, and it works.

[image]

- i've signed the app
- same app version on market

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the Merchant account, it must be active